# Will MongoDB Java driver 4.0+ retry DBCursor.next()?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I know Mongo Java driver will retry `collection.find()`, and most other read operations, per [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-reads/).

But I can't see anywhere in docs or in the [driver source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/4.1.x/driver-legacy) - will it retry `DBCursor.next()` or `DBCursor.hasNext()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not retry cursor based reads.

> Cursor.getMore() cannot be retried because of the inability for the
> client to discern if the cursor was advanced. In other words, since
> the driver does not know if the original getMore() succeeded or not,
> the driver cannot reliably know if results might be inadvertently
> skipped.

More details here - https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/retryable-reads/retryable-reads.rst#implementing-retryable-reads

Answer (score -1):

`collection.find()` will retry the whole collection, that's clear.

Now, if you are using a `while` operation, you can then use `hasNext()` operation in order to break the operation when there are not more elements.

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
  system.out.println(cursor.next())
}
```